# PHP library/client for Solr 4.0

Tags: php, solr, solrj

I wanted to upgrade my Solr engine from 3.5 to 4.0. But my old [php library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) for solr, does not seem to handle Solr 4.0 commits well. Ex  [waitFlush problem](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/issues/detail?id=75).

Is there a library/client that supports new Solr 4.0 constructs well. Or should I use some Java client etc for handling the commits?

Comment: i'm just having the same problem. the [solr-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) which is written in php has the same issue. any news on that? i guess with the php library it would not be much of a hussle fixing the protocol issues...

Comment: Well, we moved to solr-php-client. And after some trivial hacking(Ex. removing all references to waitFlush) commits are working fine. Since performance isn't a big concern for the time being, we are somewhat satisfied with it.

Comment: I went the hacking route, too. It's just a matter of removing the outdated attributes in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this bug thread](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62332), there is [an unofficial fork](https://github.com/ecaron/php-pecl-solr) of this PECL extension which can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this issue. 
Just create your own commit function. Something like this:

```
    $solrConfig= // array with solr host, port, path to collection (/solr/my_collection), 
    $solrAddress = $solrConfig['hostname'] . ':' . $solrConfig['port'] . $solrConfig['path'];
    $output = array();
    $response = exec('curl ' . $solrAddress . '/update?commit=true', $output);
```

It doesn't have to be exec() - send [php curl](http://php.net/curl) instead or You can try with send_raw_get from php solr_client but the last one is just guess. exec() worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** PECL Solr Supports Solr Server 4.0+, since version 2.0

https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=solr